# Pass a buffer and the size of the buffer as parameters

Tags: arrays, qt, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a function who fills an empty buffer (char*). It looks like :

```
void Matrix::toString(char* buffer, int sizeBuffer) const{
    char buf[sizeBuffer];
    //some code to fill buf
    //copy buf into buffer
}
```

It was working perfectly until I brought the function in QtCreator to use it with my new GUI. The compiler is telling me that he **expected a constant expression** and that he **cannot allocate an array of constant size 0** and **buf : unknown size**.

I searched a bit and I found that I had to **dynamically allocate my array**. It's working, but now I wonder..why can't I allocate it on the stack? Is it bad coding? And also, why was it working before ? 
Thanks

Comment: can you show the code?? why are you using an array of char and not std::string, QbyteArray or QString??

Comment: To allocate the array on the stack, the compiler must know what size your array needs to be, so it must be specified before runtime. This is why the error you receive is 'unknown size'. As @UmNyobe states, you'd be better off using a QString or QByteArray than a char array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is that the C++ standard doesn't allow variable length arrays. `sizeBuffer`'s value cannot be known at compile time, hence the variability. I'm not familiar with the exact reasons for this decision, but it does simplify things for the compiler and helps avoid stack overflows.

As a sidenote, I don't think you really need to be declaring a separate buffer in the first place. Can't you copy the data from your Matrix directly into the `buffer` parameter? And why not use a `QString &` argument instead? Or just return a `QString`?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. The reason I didn't use QString is simple : I didn't know I was gonna use qt when I wrote these functions. I used char* instead of std::string just because I was continuing the work of another programmer and he was using char*, so I just continued like he did.

Comment: It wasn't. Variable length arrays are never allowed in C++. Maybe `sizeBuffer` was a constant in your previous code.

Comment: I just compiled the exact same way than before and I can tell you, it's working and I don't think it's a constant..or maybe I'm missing something. Well...anyway I'm gonna change it since it looks like a bad thing to do, I was just curious!